# Matlab Finding the Zeros of a Symbolic Function

Tags: matlab, function, zero, polynomials

I have a symbolic function, whose zeros I am particular interested in knowing. I have searched through google, trying to find something related to my query, but was unsuccessful.

Could someone please help me?

EDIT:

```
T(x,t) = 72/((2*n+1)^2*pi^3)*(1 - (2*n+1)^2*pi^2*t/45 + (2*n+1)^4*pi^4*t^2/(2*45^2) - (2*n+1)^6*pi^6*t^3/(6*45^3))*(2*n+1)*pi*x/3;

for i=1:1:1000
    T_new = 72/((2*i+1)^2*pi^3)*(1 - (2*i+1)^2*pi^2*t/45 + (2*i+1)^4*pi^4*t^2/(2*45^2) - (2*i+1)^6*pi^6*t^3/(6*45^3))*(2*i+1)*pi*x/3;

    T = T + T_new;

end

T = T - 72/((2*n+1)^2*pi^3)*(1 - (2*n+1)^2*pi^2*t/45 + (2*n+1)^4*pi^4*t^2/(2*45^2) - (2*n+1)^6*pi^6*t^3/(6*45^3))*(2*n+1)*pi*x/3;

T = T(1.5,t);

T_EQ = 0.00001

S = solve(T - T_EQ == 0,t);
```

The problem that I get is that S is an a vector which contains imaginary numbers. I expected a real number, because I am trying to calculate a time.

Here is a little background as to what I am trying to do:

http://hans.math.upenn.edu/~deturck/m241/solving_the_heat_eqn.pdf

In the given link is the heat equation solved for a particular one-dimensional case. The temperature distribution, that satisfies the prescribed boundary and initial conditions, is given on page 50, I believe.

What I would like to do is find the time at which the one-dimensional object equilibrates with the environment, which is held at a constant temperature of T=0. As far as I know, the easiest way to do this would be to use the Taylor expansion of the exponential function, using only the first few terms, because I expect the equilibrium time to be relatively short; and then use the small angle approximation for the sine function, because the rod has a relatively small length. Doing just this, I made a for loop to generate terms just as the summation function would--as you can see, I used 1000 terms.

Does what I am doing seem wrong to anyone? If there is a better method, could someone please recommend it?

Comment: The most generic answer is [`sym/solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html). Assuming that you're referring to polynomials, are you interested in one zero, the zeros within a range, or all zeros? Also, what version of Matlab do you have?

Comment: Additionally, are the coefficients of your polynomials numbers or variables? And I assume that this is a standard univariate polynomial (i.e, just a function of `x`) or is it multivariate?

Comment: @horchler I updated my post, by providing more information. If you could take look, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be surprised to see imaginary roots provided that at least one root is real and positive, corresponding to your time. The question is if the time makes any sense due to the approximations that you're making. Have you plotted the the actual function to get a rough approximation for where the zero is?

I can't really comment on the particular problem you're trying to solve. You need to make sure that you're using enough Taylor expansion terms an that they are accurate for the domain. Have you tried this leaving in the `exp` and/or `sin`? Is there any reason that you can't just use zero? And have you checked that your summation has converged after 1,000 terms? Or does it converge much sooner or not at all?

The main question is why are you using symbolic math at all to solve this? This seems like a numeric problem unless you're experiencing overflow/underflow issues in your summation. You can find the zero using [`fzero`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) in this case:

```
N = 32;  % Number of terms in summation
x = 1.5;
T_EQ = 1e-5;
n = (2*(0:N)+1)*pi;
T = @(t)sum((72./n.^3).*exp(-n.^2*t/45).*sin(n*x/3))-T_EQ;
S = fzero(T,[0 1e3]) % Bounds around a root guarantees solution if function monotonic
```

which returns

```
S =

  56.333877640358708
```

If you're going to use `solve`, I'd do something like the following to avoid `for` loops:

```
syms t
N = 32;
x = 1.5;
T_EQ = 1e-5;
n = (2*sym(0:N)+1)*sym(pi);
T(t) = sum((72./n.^3).*exp(-n.^2*t/45).*sin(n*x/3));
S = double(solve(T-T_EQ==0,t))
```

or, using [`symsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symsum.html):

```
syms n t
N = 32;
x = 1.5;
T_EQ = 1e-5;
T(t) = symsum((72/(pi*(2*n+1))^3)*exp(-(pi*(2*n+1))^2*t/45)*sin(pi*(2*n+1)*x/3),n,0,N);
S = double(solve(T-T_EQ==0,t))
```

Lastly, your symbolic solutions are not even exact as some your `pi` variables are being converted to rational approximations. `pi` is floating point. Things like `pi*t` are generally safe if `t` is symbolic, because `pi` will be recognized as such. However, `pi^2` is calculated in floating-point before being converted to symbolic due to order of operations. In general your should use `sym('pi')` or `sym(pi)` in symbolic expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a polynomial or trigonometric function of x or y, and what you mean by "zeros" is the values where the function crosses the axis, i.e., either x or y is zero, you can call the value of the function when a variable is 0. An example:

```
syms x y
f=-cos(x)*exp(-(x^2)/40);
ezsurf(f,[-10,10])

F=matlabFunction(f,'vars',{[x]});
F([0])
```

The ezsurf just visualizes the plot. If you want a function of both x and y, you do something like the following:

```
syms x y
f=-cos(x)*cos(y)*exp(-(x^2+y^2)/40);
ezsurf(f,[-10,10])

F=matlabFunction(f,'vars',{[x,y]});
for y=0
    solve(f)
end
```

This will give you the value of the function for which integer multiples of x correspond to zero points for y (values of the function that are on the y=0 plane).